# Consulta com filtro java android sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, filtro

```
public ArrayList<Contato> filtrar(String filtro) {
    ArrayList<Contato> contatoArray = new ArrayList<>();

    //Consulta que traz todos dados de todas colunas
    Cursor cursor = database.query(BaseDAO.TABELA_AGENDA, BaseDAO.COLUNAS_TABELA_AGENDA, null, null, null, null, BaseDAO.CONTATO_NOME);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

        Contato c = new Contato();

        if (cursor.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase(filtro) || cursor.getString(3).equalsIgnoreCase(filtro)) {
            c.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            c.setNome(cursor.getString(1));
            c.setTelefone(cursor.getString(2));
            c.setEmpresa(cursor.getString(3));
            c.setBrunko(cursor.getInt(4) == 1);
            c.setCarter(cursor.getInt(5) == 1);
            c.setFortmetal(cursor.getInt(6) == 1);
            c.setNdflex(cursor.getInt(7) == 1);
            c.setNotus(cursor.getInt(8) == 1);
            c.setMerco(cursor.getInt(9) == 1);
            c.setMetan(cursor.getInt(10) == 1);
            c.setRiosulense(cursor.getInt(11) == 1);
            c.setYming(cursor.getInt(12) == 1);
            c.setMesContato(cursor.getInt(13));
            c.setAnoContato(cursor.getString(14));

            contatoArray.add(c);
        }
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return contatoArray;
}
```

Meu código aparentemente está correto com o `Log.d()` consegui os valores de `filtro`, `cursor.getString(1)` e `cursor.getString(3)` que são os mesmos, por exemplo "Teste Nome", "Teste Nome" e "Teste Empresa", porém eles não entram no `if()` o que está errado?

Comment: Adicione um watch nas condicionais: cursor.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase(filtro) e cursor.getString(3).equalsIgnoreCase(filtro). As duas devem estar retornando falso.

Comment: Coloque por favor um print do Log com os 3 valores: `cursor.getString(1)`, `cursor.getString(3)` e `filtro`. O ideal até era o print do `watch` em Debug para que se possa ter a certeza do conteúdo dos campos/variáveis. Em debug consegue ver o debugger a passar por cima do if quando vê esses valores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelos Log percebi que as variáveis cadastradas estavam ganhado um espaço no final delas então uma variável "x" por exemplo ficava "x ", por isso não funcionava o `if()`

Comment: Você está oferecendo uma recompensa ainda, ou já encontrou uma resposta que seja eficiente?

Answer (score 1):

Deveria colocar o filtro na consulta e então remova a condição `if`. Algo como:

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(BaseDAO.TABELA_AGENDA, BaseDAO.COLUNAS_TABELA_AGENDA, "coluna1 = ? or coluna3 = ?", new String[]{filtro, filtro}, null, null, BaseDAO.CONTATO_NOME);
```

Comment: o problema é que este é apenas um pequeno pedaço da consulta que tem mais de 400 linhas, no caso são vários `if` com diversas opções de acordo com o que o usuário envio na variável `filtro`, apenas este `if` não funciona todos os outros sim